# jquery UI tabs width 100%

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

[image]I have a need to use only 2 tabs in my application. So I want them to cover 100% of the width. Currently it aligns both tabls on left side and leave all kind of empty space on right side. What can I do so that both of my tabs cover 100% of the area.
I am using jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
            $(function(){
                // Tabs
                $('#tabs').tabs();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>My Title</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">   
                <div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                    <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
                </div><!-- Tabs --> 
            </div><!-- /content -->

        </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any chance of seeing some markup?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Via CSS set:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    width:50%;
}
```

Note due to padding, margins, and borders you may need to reduce it to less than 50%.

**Update**: If you want to center the text in the tabs, you need to make two CSS changes (keeping the 50% change from above).

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note that you can tweak the padding as needed.

Comment: do I make change to the jquery css?

Comment: You can modify the jQuery UI CSS or just add your own CSS after it since it will override any rules declared before it.

Comment: It is usually better to use your own CSS rather than modifying jQuery UI - for example, you can than easily update to new version or use tabs somewhere else on the page with different styles

Answer (score 2):

With Flexbox it's flexible and easier:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    display: flex;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    /* If placed in a small width sidebar or something like that disabling nowrap will fix the overflow issue */
    white-space: normal;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    flex: 1;
    /* If you want to align tab titles center */
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: When the default jquery-ui tab is put on normal or larger width place]

[image: When it's put a on smaller width place]